# How to replace forward slash with backward slash

Tags: c#, .net, string

i have a string `/Images/Me.jpg` i want to replace forward slashes with backward slashes like this `\Images\Me.jpg`, iam using string.Replace("/","\"); but the output is `\\Images\\Me.jpg` please help

Comment: are you using `string.Replace("/","\");` or `string.Replace("/","\\");` ? And i guess you used the debugger to inspect the content of the string which shows `\\Images\\Me.jpg`. Use the magnifier icon at the left to see the unescaped content of the string

Comment: Can't find duplicate - your code is fine, this is debugger's behavior.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

you need to escape the slashes

```
string.Replace("/", "\\")
string.Replace("/", @"\")
```

Visual studios intellisense will still show "\\", if you hover over the string, you will find a magnifying glass, click it. This will show the real string

Comment: slashes or backslashes? Not sure, just confirming.

Comment: @OptimusPrime - Its been a long day

Comment: no, still both the above types are showing the output as \\Images\\Me.jpg

Comment: Oh okie magnifier shows as \Images\Me.jpg, so why normal output shows it like that ?

Comment: To preempt the likely next question, having Visual Studios show the escaped string allows you to see the the non-space white-space characters, such as a tab ("\t") or carriage return ("\r").

Comment: @Tory - Cheers for the great explanation

Answer (score 8):

Try escaping backslash,

```
string.Replace("/","\\");
```