# How to catch path/string in the correct way?

Tags: c#, string, replace, path, str-replace

i'm searching for the best practise catching the possibility that path does not start with Path1.
Something like path is equal to "C:\\test\yes" and a.Setting.PathSettings.Path1 is equal to "C:\test\".

How can i avoid a failure?

```
String path1 = "C:\test\yes";
String path2 = "C:\test\yes";

pathDir = new FileInfo("C:\\\test\yes\test.txt").Directory.FullName;
pathDir = pathDir.Replace(a.Setting.PathSettings.Path1, a.Setting.PathSettings.Path2);
```

Kind regards

Comment: I don't understand your question. Do you want to chekc your path include `Path1` or not?

Comment: can I ask why it matters? using hard coded paths is a bad idea and for example any checks as to what specific *drive* a file is on would indicate not very good programming and file handling

Comment: the format changed..  what i mean is string.replace can't compare "C:\\test" with "C\test"

Comment: Is this related to my [last sentence in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18278908/1324033)?, `C\test` wouldn't be a valid path

Comment: @sayse a bit :), edit: may it's more clearly now. Or maybe i see problem where no problems are :).  Which format has FileInfo.Directory.FullName? And can it change?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do, you can use `File.Move` to move/rename a file? have a look at the [Path class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.aspx) for loads of helpful path specific methods

Answer (score 0):

You could check with String.StartsWith

```
if(path.StartsWith(a.Settings.PathSettings.Path1)
{
  path=path.Replace(a.Setting.PathSettings.Path1, a.Setting.PathSettings.Path2);
}
```