# How to replace backslash '\' with slash '/'?

Tags: c#, .net, replace, backslash

In my code I want to replace backslash character `\` by a forward slash character `/` in a string. I've tried the following code:

```
string str = chosen_file.Replace("/", @"\");
```

where, `chosen_file` is a `string` which contains numerous occurances of the `\` character.
But it doesn't seem to be working.

Can I know any other solutions for this issue?

Comment: Not a duplicate, answers in other question do not answer this user's question.

Comment: How do you know the string contains backslash?

Comment: @BasBrekelmans: How does http://stackoverflow.com/q/18278892/15541 not address the question?

Comment: @leppie OP is already escaping slashes

Comment: @BasBrekelmans: Oops, did not notice that ;p

Answer (score 6):

If you look at the definition of String.Replace:

```
public string Replace(
    string oldValue,
    string newValue
)
```

and your call:

```
chosen_file.Replace("/", @"\");
```

You are replacing forward slashses with backslashes. If you swap the arguments you should be getting the desired behavior.

Comment: yeah... actually there was a mistake in previous lines and i could solve it now.. thanks a lot for your suggestion. Its working now!!

Answer (score 1):

Double slash will show only at the time of debugging.If you print this value in console application or lable box then you can see the correct answer.