# Replace all blackslashes with forward slash

Tags: c#, string, .net-core, replace

What is the best way to replace all occurrences of "" with "/" in a string in c#?

I've tried the following options but neither work.

- variable.Replace("", "/");
- variable.Replace(@"", @"/");

Comment: In .NET, [strings are immutable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2365272/why-net-string-is-immutable).

Comment: you have to assign the result

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and share your research.

Comment: Check this one: [How to replace backslash '\' with slash '/'?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24823472/5588347)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should assign result of replacement:

```
var res = variable. Replace("\\", "/"); //  you need "\\" because "\" is escape symbol.
```

or

```
var res = variable.Replace(@"\", "/");
```

Comment: `"\"` won't compile.

Comment: Here: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/41935234/revisions

Comment: @UweKeim, sorry, I was editing answer when you left comment

Answer (score 2):

As @UweKeim says in a comment, you have to store the result of the `Replace` call. Like this:

```
variable = variable.Replace("@"\", @"/");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var newVar = variable.Replace("\\", "/");
```

Comment: This won't compile.

Comment: But this will... `var newVar = variable.Replace("\\", "/"); '

Comment: Why will it not compile?

Comment: @Ben. You've modified your code. See my comment for your original code: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/41935242/revisions

Comment: SO stripped my double backslash because it wasn't in code blocks, so i reformatted it..

Comment: You need to escape the backslash.

Comment: I did, but the original was without code blocks and SO removed the the backslash lmao, you guys are so judgemental, i literally fixed it within seconds

Comment: @Ben there's some sort of syntax crusader mentality on this site that can definitely be beneficial but feels so abused and overused