# Losing quotes or getting extra \ sign arround string

Tags: c#

Here is something pretty basic for c# String class.

```
//I get string error as input parameter
string error = "Hello World!";
string eventHandlerStr = "onmouseover = 'ShowError(" + "event" + ", \"" + error + "\")'";
// result is "onmouseover = 'ShowError(event, \"Hello World!"\)'"
```

How to get result without \ around "Hello World!"? And I need quotes arround Hello World!
If I do this:

```
string eventHandlerStr = "onmouseover = 'ShowError(" + "event" + ", " + error + ")'";
```

I get Hello World! without quotes.

I tried even removing \ character with String.Remove method but \ stayed there after removing.

Comment: Where are you seeing this string? If its the debugger you are probably looking at the escaped string, click the magnifying glass

Comment: To quote Tory's comment on [an answer to a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18278908/1324033)... "Visual Studios show the escaped string allows you to see the the non-space white-space characters, such as a tab ("\t") or carriage return ("\r")."

Answer (score 1):

Try verbatim string -> **@**

Here you are everything you need:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090(v=vs.71).aspx

**UPDATE 2018/06/07**

New documentation from MS:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/verbatim (second point)

Cache from WebArchive for original link: https://web.archive.org/web/20170730011023/https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: This Microsoft page now shows this text: The content you requested has already been retired.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
string format = @"onmouseover = 'ShowError(event, ""{0}"")'";
string error = "HelloWorld";
string pqr = string.Format(format, error);
```